# Changing the order of a double integration

Tags: calculus

Change the order of integration in  $x \in [0, 2a]$ and $y \in [0,  \sqrt{2ax-x^2}]$ for the integrand
$$\frac{(x^3 + y^2 x)}{\sqrt{4 a^2 x^2 - (x^2 + y^2)^2}} \text{d}x \text{d}y$$ 
and evaluate it.

After changing the order, I found out the limits of integration as $y$ varies from $0$ to $a$ and $x$ varies from $a-\sqrt{a^2 - y^2}$ to $a+\sqrt{a^2 - y^2}$.

But I couldn't solve it. I dont know how to find the substitution for easily evaluating integration. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, letting $u=x^2+y^2$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\frac{x \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{4 a^2 x^2-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}}dx\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{4 a^2 x^2-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}}d(x^2+y^2)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{u}{\sqrt{4 a^2(u-y^2)-u^2}}du\\
&=&2 a^2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{u-2
   a^2}{2a\sqrt{a^2 -y^2}}\right)-\sqrt{4 a^2
   \left(u-y^2\right)-u^2}\\
&=&2 a^2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2+y^2-2a^2}{2a\sqrt{a^2- y^2}}\right)-\sqrt{4 a^2 x^2-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} \\
&\equiv&F(x),
\end{eqnarray}
and
$$ F(a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2})=-\frac{a^2\pi}{2} $$
and
$$ F(a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2})=\frac{a^2\pi}{2}.$$
So
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^{2a}\int_0^{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}\frac{x \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{4 a^2 x^2-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}}dydx\\
&=&\int_0^{a}\int_{a-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}^{a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}\frac{x \left(x^2+y^2\right)}{\sqrt{4 a^2 x^2-\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}}dxdy\\
&=&\int_0^{a}a^2\pi dy\\
&=&a^3\pi^2.
\end{eqnarray}